# Скрытые объекты на сцене

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим, имеется `10` скрытых объектов на сцене.

**Вопрос:** будут ли они загружаться при `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` сразу в память, как, например, при использовании `Instantiate`?

То есть, чтобы мне не создавать постоянно через `Instantiate`, я просто сразу поставил на сцену и выключил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загрузка сцены, по сути, это тот же `Instantiate`, просто оно за вас делается для всех подэлементов.

Так что, отвечая на вопрос, да, они будут сразу грузиться в память. Но, т.к. они выключены, к примеру, `MonoBehaviour` скрипты на них не будут работать.

Если у вас подобных выключенных объектов много, то рекомендую их грузить асинхронно отдельно от сцены после загрузки самой сцены.

Comment: Замечательно - прекрасно =), не, их всего 10 =) Мне нужно было убедиться, что они действительно будут загружаться, чтобы потом рывков при включении не было, как например происходит это при `Instantiate`.. ответ полностью устраивает, выбрать смогу только позже, сейчас не дает этого сделать, почему-то. Странно!

Comment: @ОтражаемоеИмя рывки, вполне вероятно могут быть. Т.к. факт того, что они загрузились в память, не означает, что они полноценно инициализировались.

Comment: Хорошо, проверю, отпишу, но уже не сегодня.

Comment: Рывки могут возникнуть при включении этих объектов - вызовутся Awake/Start.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, там по сути в этих методах, ничего сложного нет и что-то весомого. Только просто `position = transform.position;`, больше ничего нет.

Comment: @ОтражаемоеИмя тогда при таком количестве и с таким кодом все должно пройти гладко :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, вы просто выручатели, лююююди- человеки =), чтобы я без вас делал =).